# How to apply hue on UIImage using pixel Buffer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-image

i have seen the code of implementation of saturation , i found it very nice . But i want to implement hue also like in this way .

code of saturation --

```
void filterSaturate(UInt8 *pixelBuf, UInt32 offset, void *context)
{
double t = *((double*)context);



int r = offset;
int g = offset+1;
int b = offset+2;

int red = pixelBuf[r];
int green = pixelBuf[g];
int blue = pixelBuf[b];

int avg = ( red + green + blue ) / 3;

pixelBuf[r] = SAFECOLOR((avg + t * (red - avg)));
pixelBuf[g] = SAFECOLOR((avg + t * (green - avg)));
pixelBuf[b] = SAFECOLOR((avg + t * (blue - avg)));  
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to apply a hue shift without first choosing a color to shift toward. However, all you have to do is convert the pixel colors to HSB(HSV), and change the H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the important code, taken from Alex Stone's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9525040/2533772):

```
-(UIImage*)doHueAdjustFilterWithBaseImageName:(NSString*)baseImageName hueAdjust:(CGFloat)hueAdjust
{

    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:baseImageName]];
    CIFilter * controlsFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
    [controlsFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    [controlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:hueAdjust] forKey:@"inputAngle"];

    NSLog(@"%@",controlsFilter.attributes);
    CIImage *displayImage = controlsFilter.outputImage;
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:displayImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    if (displayImage == nil || finalImage == nil) {
        // We did not get output image. Let's display the original image itself.
       return  [UIImage imageNamed:baseImageName];
    }else {
        // We got output image. Display it.
        return  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:displayImage fromRect:displayImage.extent]];
    }    
}
```

Very neat, very easy to see what's happening, gets the job done.

Comment: I know about this code but actually i want to change the value of input angle on slider , as i am doing it is not fluent because filters do take time in processing .

Comment: So you want like a preview of the filtered image in real-time, as the slider is slid?

Comment: yes i want real time preview.